# terminal clear function doesn't work for me in c++

Tags: c++, terminal

I tried to make program which clear the terminal, I used system("CLR")[invalid command] system("clear")[says that TERM doesn't set, but echo $TERM prints it's value] system("clr")[invalid command] nothing works for my in CLion in manjaro KDE plasma

Comment: Shouldn't it be "cls"

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question. And specify what OS/terminal you are using

Comment: @SerkanPekçetin no.. it doesnt

Comment: @idclev463035818
int a;
std::cin>>a;
system("CLR");
std::cout<<a;